# an implement of sizeof guaranteeing bit alignment

Tags: c, sizeof

A `define` sentence is:

```
#define _INTSIZEOF(n)   ( (sizeof(n) + sizeof(int) - 1) & ~(sizeof(int) - 1) )
```

I have been told the purpose is bit alignment.
I wonder how it works, thx in advance.

Comment: Try working a few examples by hand, and you should see how it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The above macro simply aligns the size of `n` to the nearest greater-or-equal `sizeof(int)` boundary.

The basic algorithm for aligning value `a` to the nearest greater-or-equal *arbitrary* boundary `b` is to

1. Divide `a` by `b` rounding *up*, and then
2. Multiply the quotient by `b` again.

In the domain of unsigned (or just positive) values the first step is achieved by the following popular trick

```
q = (a + b - 1) / b
// where `/` is ordinary C-style integer division (rounding down)
// Now `q` is `a` divided by `b` rounded up
```

Combining this with the second step we get the following

```
aligned_a = (a + b - 1) / b * b
```

In `aligned_a` you get the desired aligned value.

Applying this algorithm to the problem at hand one would arrive at the following implementation of `_INTSIZEOF` macro

```
#define _INTSIZEOF(n)\
  ( (sizeof(n) + sizeof(int) - 1) / sizeof(int) * sizeof(int) )
```

This is already good enough.

However, if you know in advance that the alignment boundary is a power of 2, you can "optimize" the calculations by replacing the divide+multiply sequence with a simple bitwise operation

```
aligned_a = (a + b - 1) & ~(b - 1)
```

That is exactly what's done in the above original implementation of `_INTSIZEOF` macro.

This "optimization" might probably make sense with some compilers (although I would expect a modern compiler to be able to figure it out by itself). However, considering that the above `_INTSIZEOF(n)` macro is apparently intended to serve as a compile-time expression (it does not depend on any run-time values, barring VLA objects/types passed as `n`), there's not much point in optimizing it that way.

Comment: May I ask anther question? I use `<stdarg.h>` to handle variable argument function, but it failed when the paraments list are all char type, i don't know why :(

Comment: @PyLion: This is too unrelated. Start a separate question and provide more details. Anyway, `char` values are implicitly promoted to `int` when you pass them as variadic arguments.

Comment: [`For functions without prototype, or parameters corresponding to the ellipsis ..., the default argument promotions are performed. Those are: Default integer promotions and promotion of float to double. Default integer promotions: Every integer type of rank less than int is promoted to int or unsigned int.`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22846016/4510033) And this is the reason why `_INTSIZEOF(n)` macro is needed.

Comment: @K. _: I don't see the connection.

Comment: @AnT Oh, you've never said anything about _variadic functions_.. I'm so sorry, I was reading articles about _variadic functions_ and it seems I was confused. -- With Visual C++, for compilations that target x86 processors, several macros to support _variadic functions_ such as `va_start`, `va_arg` use `_INTSIZEOF`; and the reason is _default argument promotions_ I excerpted above, which make the arguments' size bigger than or equal to `sizeof(int)`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a hint:

A common method to do `ceil(a/b)` is:

```
(a + (b-1)) / b
```

Comment: Which, when `b` is some power of two, may be further simplified as in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

b * ( (a + b - 1) / b ) = (a + b - 1) & ~(b - 1)

To see why the above holds, consider this:

Part I (why q = (a + b - 1) / b produces the number we are looking for):

... note that we want q to be the number of b's that are in a, but rounded up (i.e., if after integer division, there is a remainder, then that remainder should be rounded up to b and hence q incremented by 1).

there exists Q and R such that a = Qb + R, and hence a + b - 1 = Qb + b - 1 + R. If we perform integer division on a + b - 1 by b we would get Q + (b-1+R)/b. The 2nd part of this will be zero if R is zero and 1 if R is not zero (note R is guaranteed to be less than b).

Part II (the macro):

now if b is a power of two, then integer division of a + b - 1 by b is simply a right shift of the exponent of b (i.e., b = 2^n, then shift right by n places).

in addition, multiplication by b is a left shift (shift left by n places)

hence combined, all we are doing is clearing the rightmost n bits to zero, and this is accomplished by masking: ~(b-1) gives us 1111...111000...0 where the number of 1s is equal to n (b = 2^n)