# What default promotions of types are there in the variadic arguments list?

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

For example, I use `printf` function in C++ for 8-bit CPU (AVR). Is the following code safe:

```
uint8_t a = 5;
printf("%d", a);
```

Here `%d` expects `int` (16-bit in my case, and at least 16-bit in any case), but I pass 8-bit integer.

Does C/C++ standards guarantee that any type with rank lesser than `int` promoted to `int`?

The same question for `float a` and `%f` that expects `double`, and other analogous types.

Comment: Yes, the code is safe, for the reason you guessed.

Comment: Best download the latest draff standard, and read for yourself. Default promotions: integers of rank < int >> int, float >> double, that was it.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I'm interested only promotions in variadic functions. `printf("%d", a)` isn't the same as `print_int(a)` (where `print_int` expect `int` argument), because compiler don't know **what** a variadic function expects in `...`. I look the draft, but can't find answer for my question.

Comment: 6.5.2.2 Function calls

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatic Type promotion in variadic function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7084857/automatic-type-promotion-in-variadic-function)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look in the draft [n1256 (C99 with Technical corrigenda TC1, TC2, and TC3 included)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) for `6.5.2.2 Function calls`:

For functions without prototype, or parameters corresponding to the ellipsis `...`, the default argument promotions are performed.

Those are: Default integer promotions and promotion of `float` to `double`.

Default integer promotions: Every integer type of rank less than `int` is promoted to `int` or `unsigned int`.