# 'Char' is promoted to 'int' when passed through in C

Tags: c

I have a question. I have line in my program:

`sprintf(buff,"Nieznany znak: %d",(char)va_arg(x, const char)); break;`

Why after compile I have an error:

```
error.c: In function 'error':
error.c:30:46: warning: 'char' is promoted to 'int' when passed through '...' [e
nabled by default]
  case 0xfe: sprintf(buff,"Nieznany znak: %d",(char)va_arg(x, const char)); brea
k;
                                              ^
error.c:30:46: note: (so you should pass 'int' not 'char' to 'va_arg')
error.c:30:46: note: if this code is reached, the program will abort
```

In my opinion everything is okay, why I can't do this like that?

Comment: Strong recommendation: break your expression into two statements.

Comment: This is a duplicate of something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844360/c-c-variadic-functions-and-default-promotions

Comment: @PaulRoub If by "you can" you mean "it's legal" or "it will work": the answer to that is "no, you can't".

Comment: automatic promotion of char to int in passed arguments is part of the C language.  Amongst other reasons, a parameter the size of int means uniformity in stack handling.  (this is also one of the reasons to pass parameters by reference, rather than by value.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The compiler **just told you** why:

```
'char' is promoted to 'int' when passed through '...'
```

According to the C language specification, usual arithmetic conversions are applied to the unnamed arguments of variadic functions. Hence, any integer type shorter than `int` (e. g. `bool`, `char` and `short`) are implicitly converted `int`; `float` is promoted to `double`, etc.

Do what the compiler asks you for (use `va_arg()` with `int` as its second parameter), else your code will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: This isn't "the usual arithmetic", but rather a special oddball rule called _the default argument promotions_. "The usual" only apply when you have several operands to an operator.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in this [link](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/EXP47-C.+Do+not+call+va_arg+with+an+argument+of+the+incorrect+type)

> "This noncompliant code example attempts to read a variadic argument of type unsigned char with va_arg(). However, when a value of type unsigned char is passed to a variadic function, the value undergoes default argument promotions, resulting in a value of type int being passed."

Solution:

Access variadic function with type int and cast it back to unsigned char (or char)

```
unsigned char c = (unsigned char) va_arg(ap, int);
```