# arithmetic overflow because signed characters in C program

Tags: c, output

We know that `signed char` can have values only from `-128` to `127`.
but when we run the below program no overflow happens even though the l output exceeds the range of signed character.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    char i = 60;
    char j = 30;
    char k = 10;
    char l = (i*j)/k;
    printf("%d ", l);

    return 0;
}
```

> the output of `l` is `180` which is out of range for `char l`, but i am not getting any error.

in other scenario if we take the same program but instead of arithmetic function if we simply put `l=180` and try to print it then we get wrong answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    char i = 60;
    char j = 30;
    char k = 10;
    char l = 180;
    printf("%d ", l);

    return 0;
}
```

the answer that i get in 2nd case is `-76`.
can anyone explain it why? even if i am virtually executing the same thing but i am getting different result.

> EDIT:

This is the classic example that the intermediate computations are made in `int` and not `char`

so in 1st when i am doing computation it is taking all values in int and in the later part i am explicitly mentioning it as char.

Comment: Maybe your compiler is broken ? What compiler do you use ?

Comment: The first snippet is not reproducible: https://ideone.com/B4b4AJ

Comment: I would say it's the optimization. The expression is just evaluated as `int` right in the print statement. Or you are not telling the truth.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why is the optimizer allowed to break truncation to char ?

Comment: @marcolz , no my compiler is not broken , i have tested the above program on two ide say DEVC++ and VS2015 , even you can try the above two version of same program and can yourself see that the answers are differing in-spite they are saying the same logic.

Comment: @marcolz Not sure it is allowed.. it's rather the second part of the comment.

Comment: @ Eugene Sh , sir you can yourself check them by running on any of your IDE , i am getting different results from both program.

Comment: reproducable on SuSE linux on IBAN zSeries gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.3.4, optimization level -O3

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Does it exhibit the same without optimization?

Comment: On gcc 4.8.4 I can only reproduce it when I specify unsigned char.

Comment: It's 180 even with -O0 on IBM Z

Comment: Integer overflow is UB.  Your compiler's optimizer uses it to eliminate the l variable completely.  Fast always trumps accurate.  Doesn't work in the 2nd case since the compiler has already generated -76.

Comment: @HansPassant There is no overflow in the calculation itself, only in the conversion to `char`. And conversion of a value that doesn't fit in a smaller signed integer type is implementation-defined, not UB.

Comment: @interjay But implementation-defined behavior can't explain the described behavior, as it is not about casting only here..

Comment: It turns to be an interesting question.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I didn't offer an explanation (I see no other explanation than a compiler bug or a mistake by OP), I only said that it isn't UB.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is states that it *is* UB though, as the result of the calculation is a signed integer.

Comment: @marcolz But where is the overflow here?

Comment: The result should be the same. This is a compiler (optimization) bug.

Comment: @2501 Now I *think* the problem is with the fact that `printf`s `va_arg` do not actually have any type information, so the integer promotion we *would* expect doesn't actually happen, making it either UB or unspecified. Not a bug. The difference is in the memory content extending `l`

Comment: @EugeneSh. the overflow is trying to fit 180 into a (presumed) signed char. That would make this UB and thus the results need not be the same. va_arg actually does promote integer types smaller than int to int.

Comment: @2501 Exactly. This is the problem here. It expects `int` for `%d`, so reads the whole `int` memory in place of `char`.

Comment: @marcolz Read the thread. It is implementation defined.

Comment: @2501 oh ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983471/char-is-promoted-to-int-when-passed-through-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844360/what-default-promotions-of-types-are-there-in-the-variadic-arguments-list

Comment: @EugeneSh. Actually I have misspoken. Var-args function performs default argument promotions which include integer promotions.

Comment: @2501 Hm. In this case I can't come up with anything but a bug..

Comment: I just found your comment stating that converting 180, which is an int to signed char is UB. It isn't because C11 6.3.1.3.p3 states it is implementation defined.

Comment: The owner accepted the answer that stated that is claim was false, in the mean time..

Comment: Another proof that something starting with "We know that ..." or similar phrase is wrong >95% of the times. whether `char` is signed is implementation dependent. And `signed char` has a **minimum range of `-127..127`.  can be much larger, though.

Comment: @marcolz I would rather see his explicit comment about it. Also see  Ingo Leonhardts comments above.

Comment: Please state your target platform (CPU, OS, compiler details)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you did and test what you described in the first snippet?
If it is run, it <del>overflows</del> wraps around as expected.

It makes a big difference if you did

```
char l = (i*j)/k;
printf("%d ", l);
```

And if you did

```
printf("%d ", (i*j)/k);
```

As in the second case, the compiler would infer the usage of an `int` as the output, (the result could not fit inside a char without wrapping around obviously), and primarily because the intermediate computations are made in `int` and not `char`.

In addition, consider that the result actually fits inside an `unsigned char`, so check this case too.

In your case, I would start thinking cases of a problematic compiler too, but only after I am sure what the program executed should do.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This actually can be an answer, even if not explicitly; the answer to this answer is the answer to thw question.

Comment: I really don't see how this answers the question. It might answer a different question, but not this one.

Comment: There is no overflow in the code. Jut conversion, which **may be** implementation defined for this constellation, but  is not UB.

Comment: It is right that there is no overflow, I should mention wrapping around instead.

Comment: @NickL. I am not the downvoter, though as I said, I don't see how the answer is explaining what the OP apparently sees. But the ultimate answer should. And I am unable to suggest how to improve it as I don't know the correct answer as probably you don't. That's it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You are right, and I think that the problem is in the question itself. I ran the code posted, and the result was different - and already mentioned by others. I supposed there is a possibility that the OP posted some code he was remembering from a meeting and/or a conversation but not exactly as it was. This pushed me to try guessing what he was meaning, and then attempted to answer it, by attempting to cover all cases. But I agree this is not the best answer given, and I doubt there is one.

Answer (score 3):

The C language is actually unable to perform any form of calculations on `char` types. `char` is a *small integer type*, meaning that whenever it appears as part of an expression, it always gets implicitly promoted to `int`. This is called *integer promotion* or *the integer promotion rules*.

In addition, there is another implicit type conversion back to `char`, since you store the result, which is of type `int`, inside a `char`. This is called *lvalue conversion*: it converts the result of an expression to the type of the designated object.

```
char l = (i*j)/k;
```

is therefore completely equivalent to

```
char l = (char)( (int)i * (int)j / (int)k );
```

Since all arithmetic is carried out on type `int`, there are no overflows. The result 180 may or may not fit inside a `char`.

You should avoid using `char` for any form of arithmetic, because it has implementation-defined signedness. On one system it might be signed, -128 to 127, on another system it might be unsigned, 0 to 255. Use `uint8_t` instead, it is a better and safer type.

Comment: While good as a general suggestion, it still offers no explanation to the behavior exhibited. the second snippet clearly suggests that `180` does not fit into the OPs `char`.

Comment: An alterrnative is to use `unsigned char` wherever an arithmetic result has to stored. That guarantees the same or larger range as `uint8_t`.

Answer (score -2):

This happens because intermediate calculations are with int, not with char. char may be signed or unsigned, but the specs themselves say char, signed char and unsigned char are 3 distinct types.

EDIT: Found out why this happens: Signed char overflows, which triggers **undefined behavior**. That's why you don't get a constant. Signed integral types (signed char, signed int, signed long) all trigger undefined behavior on overflow. Optimization is allowed to do anything, although it mostly consists on ignoring the existence of the overflow.

Comment: The intermediate calculations are with `int`, but the assignment to `char l` will force a conversion to `char`. The actual value written is implementation-defined but I don't see how it could be 180 (assuming signed `char`).

Comment: int is at least 16 bits and can hold the product well enough. char may be unsigned.

Comment: Yes, `int` can hold the product, but that doesn't help if you then convert it to `char` as is done here. And the second example shows that `char` is signed on OP's machine.

Comment: The division takes two ints, 1800 and 10 and gives 180; this 180 itself is required to fit the char, not the intermediate values.

Comment: "this 180 itself is required to fit the char," - But it *doesn't* fit in signed char.

Comment: Allowing both values to exist though is a weird thing indeed (as char is only 8 bits, 180 and -76 are equivalent)

Comment: @PaulStelian: While likely true here, `char` is not required to have 8 bits. OP does not mention the target platform.

Comment: char is required to be 1 byte, and 1 byte is 8 bits in most cases. @Olaf

Comment: @PaulStelian Please state a reference to where the standard defines a byte as 8 bits! (hint: you will not find any!) For the "most cases" see the first part of my comment. Still there is no UB..