# Wrong output sprintf C51 8051 MCU embedded system

Tags: c, printf, keil, 8051, c51

I have the following fragment of C code for an AT89S52 microcontroller:

```
unsigned char x = 0x10;
unsigned char str[21];

sprintf(str, "%u", (x >> 4) );
```

sprintf function prototype in stdio.h:

```
extern int sprintf  (char *, const char *, ...);
```

Can someone tell me why does my string contain **"256"** instead of **"1"** ?, the x variable isn't even big enough to hold the 256 value.

I'm compiling with KEIL uVision 5, using the standard stdio.h library.

If I use:

```
void UlToStr(char *s, unsigned long bin, unsigned char n)
{
    s += n;
    *s = '\0';

    while (n--)
    {
        *--s = (bin % 10) + '0';
        bin /= 10;
    }
}
```

instead of sprintf the string holds a '1'.

Im verifying the content of the string printing it through a char-LCD 40x4 (KS 0066 compatible controller)

```
str_lecd1(str);
```

with the following functions:

```
void str_lcd1(unsigned char *a)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
     data_lcd1(a[i]);
    delay(10);
}

void data_lcd1(unsigned char x)
{
    P1 = x;
    rs = 1;
    en1 = 1;                
    delay(4);
    en1=0;
    delay(4);
}
```

Comment: I find it hard to believe that this code is behaving as described.

Comment: Are you sure that shift is what you show us? Or the initial value of `x`?

Comment: How do you know what the string is containing?

Comment: Also, when passing values of smaller types (like `char` or `short`) to a vararg function (like `printf`) those values will be [*promoted*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to `int` or possible `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The result of `>>` is already `int`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the function prototype follows "extern int sprintf  (char *, const char *, ...); " I'm pretty sure. Also proved the same code isolated and even compiled for Windows with printf and it worked.

Comment: Does those three lines produce a string containing the integer `16`? I serisously doubt that. [`1` I would believe](https://ideone.com/KEpfxD).

Comment: @EugeneSh. Im printing the string's content through and LCD char by char.

Comment: Then show us the full (but minimal) reproducing code (like in [mcve])

Comment: Then it's more likely a problem with your LCD functions. Either that or a bug in the compiler (which can happen but very *very* unlikely).

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yeah should show 1, my bad.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I dont think so, I used another function to build the string. void UlToStr(char *s, unsigned long bin, unsigned char n)
{
    s += n;
    *s = '\0';

    while (n--)
    {
        *--s = (bin % 10) + '0';
        bin /= 10;
    }
} and it worked without a problem.

Comment: Without [mcve] this question will get closed as non-reproducible, as in any compliant C implementation this code will produce string `"1"`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. that's the fragment of the code that gives me trouble with sprinft. I proved it with another function I added below and also compiled it for Windows with printf and worked correctly.

Comment: Could this be an endian issue?  `"%u"` indicates you are copying to an `unsigned int`.  Seeing as you are using an 8-bit microcontroller, it is likely two bytes.  If you print those two bytes to the LCD in the wrong order, then 0x0001 could easily be read as 0x0100, or 256.

Comment: What result do you get for x=0x01 and you simply print x? Repeat for 0x02. Repeat for 0x02 printing x>>1

Comment: @christian gibbons How can this ever happen if the string is in decimal?

Comment: @MLuna No it is not. If you want to get help, please provide the information people are asking you to provide.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Hmm, yes, it seems I had gotten myself mixed up.

Comment: @EugeneSh. edited so you can see the functions I use to send ascii to the LCD.

Comment: also note that strictly speaking `sprintf(srt, "%u", (x >> 4) );` invokes undefined behavior, since `%u` expects an `unsigned` and not an int (which is the type of `x >> 4`). However did you try attaching a debugger to check or send the characters via UART to the PC?

Comment: @phuclv why do you say x>>4 is an int type if x is a unsigned char type?. I also tried with %d and got the same results. Don't have any debugger at hands right now but I'll try and post my results.

Comment: @MLuna because `unsigned char` fits in an `int`, unless `sizeof(unsigned char) == sizeof(int)` which is not true on 8051 [Is unsigned char always promoted to int?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17882326/995714), ['Char' is promoted to 'int' when passed through in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23983471/995714)

Comment: @phuclv I'm confused. Then why would it be promoted if in the function prototype it states that the function expects a char type parameter? (I just added it to the post)

Comment: [Implicit type promotion rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46073295/implicit-type-promotion-rules)

Comment: `extern int sprintf  (char *, const char *, ...);` means the first two parameters must have those types, the remaining will be passed using [default promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1255775/995714). You don't pass the integer in the first two arguments, do you? Beside that any types narrower than int will be promoted to int

Comment: @phuclv I see... well, I've been trying to look for the source of the problem. When I run `#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char x = 0x10;
unsigned char str[20];

void main(void)
{
 sprintf(str, "%u", (x>>4));
 printf("%s", str);
}` for X86 it works properly... I have no idea of what could be happening here... Thank you for your support.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons you were right! even though the function prototype states that it takes char type as arguments whenever I use int types or cast the char variable to int it works fine. Also verified that the numbers I was getting were indeed in the wrong order.

Comment: The code in your question does not compile. You define your array as `str` and refer to it as `srt`. We can't tell what other errors you might have introduced while typing the code into your question -- which is why you should always copy-and-paste the *exact* code that you're compiling. If I replace `(x >> 4)` by `(x << 4)`, I get `"256"` in `str` (because the integer promotions convert `x` from `unsigned char` to `int`). Please read this: [mcve]

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks for the correction regarding str and srt. I already fixed that. I also mentioned that I used Keil uVision v5 IDE with a AT89s52 microcontroller, are you also using the same IDE and microcontroller?

Comment: @MLuna: No, I'm not using the same system. Does your actual code have `(x >> 4)` or `(x << 4)`? Is the first code fragment in your question copy-and-pasted from your actual source code? (I vaguely recall that Keil is non-conforming in some areas, possibly involving integer promotions.)

Comment: @KeithThompson yes, it is copy-pasted.

Comment: @MLuna: Then I suspect a compiler bug. (That's rarely a good guess, but in this case I think it is.)  Given `unsigned char x = 0x10;`, `(x << 4)` yields a result of type `int` with the value `1`. `%u` expects an argument of type `unsigned int`, but an `int` argument is ok as long as it's with the range of both types. The other possibility is that you're mistaken about the contents of `str` (or that my reasoning is incorrect, which is always possible).

Comment: Yes, I've run into this before, and I answered a question about what appears to be the same problem you've run into. I'll close this as a duplicate. (It's not an endianness issue.)

Comment: @KeithThompson understood, thank you for the help. Voted to delete my answer so people dont get confused.