# Can %c be given a negative int argument in printf?

Tags: c, char, int, printf, negative-number

Can I pass a negative int in `printf` while printing through format specifier `%c` since while printing `int` gets converted into an unsigned char? Is `printf("%c", -65);` valid? — I tried it on GCC but getting a diamond-like character(with question-mark inside) as output. Why?

Comment: Which representation would you expect instead if you print value `-65`? `char` type is not only used to store printable characters. It is also a rather short type for numerical values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely yes, if `char` is a signed type. C allows `char` to be [either signed or unsigned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2054939/995714) and in GCC you can switch between them with [`-funsigned-char` and `-fsigned-char`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options). When char is signed it's exactly the same thing as this

```
char c = -65;
printf("%c", c);
```

When passing to `printf()` the `char` variable will be **sign-extended** to `int` so `printf()` will also see -65 like if it's passed from a constant. `printf` simply has no way to differentiate between `printf("%c", c);` and `printf("%c", -65);` due to [default promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22844360/995714) in variadic functions.

The printing result **depends on the character encoding** though. For example in the [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) or [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) charsets you'll see `¿` because `(unsigned char)-65 == 0xBF`. In UTF-8 (which is a variable-length encoding) 0xBF is not allowed as a character in the starting position. That's why you see � which is the replacement character for invalid bytes

> Please tell me why the code point 0 to 255 are not mapped to 0 to 255 in unsigned char. I mean that they are non-negative so shouldn't I just look through the UTF-8 character set for their corresponding values?

The mapping is not done by relative position in the range as you thought, i.e. code point 0 maps to the `CHAR_MIN`, code point 40 maps to `CHAR_MIN + 40`, code point 255 maps to `CHAR_MAX`... In two's complement systems it's typically a simple mapping based on the value of the **bit pattern** when treating as unsigned. That's because the way values are usually truncated from a wider type. In C a character literal like `'a'` has type int. Suppose `'a'` is mapped to code point 130 in some theoretical character set then the below lines are equivalent

```
char c = 'a';
char c = 130;
```

Either way `c` will be assigned a value of `'a'` after casting to char, i.e. `(char)'a'`, which may be a negative value

So code points 0 to 255 **are** mapped to 0 to 255 in unsigned char. That means code point code point 0x1F will be stored in a char (signed or unsigned) with value 0x1F. Code point 0xBF will be mapped to 0xBF if char is unsigned and -65 if char is signed

I'm assuming 8-bit char for all the above things. Also note that UTF-8 is an *encoding* for the Unicode character set, it's **not** a charset on its own so you can't look up UTF-8 code points

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213418/discussion-on-answer-by-phuclv-can-c-be-given-a-negative-int-argument-in-printf).